# How to query LDAP from Java to get an object's DN from the "netbiosDomain\samAccountName" from Active Directory

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I need to query LDAP from Java to convert `netbiosDomain\samAccountName` of a user or group to `distinguishedName`.

For example

There are two child domains:
 * `DC=northeast,DC=domain,DC=com`
 * `DC=southeast,DC=domain,DC=com`

And there are 2 different users:

- `NORTHEAST\NICKD` = `CN=nickd,CN=Users,DC=northeast,DC=domain,DC=com`
- `SOUTHEAST\NICKD` = `CN=nickd,CN=Users,DC=southeast,DC=domain,DC=com`

Given `NORTHEAST\NICKD`, how can I query ldap to convert that to `CN=nickd,CN=Users,DC=northeast,DC=domain,DC=com`?

Basically, the question can be re-asked: How can I query LDAP for the distingushedName of a netbios domain?

The answer here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/dbbeeefd-001b-4d1d-93cb-b44b0d5ba155/how-do-you-search-for-a-domain-samaccountname-in-active-directory?forum=winserverDS&prof=required provides a vbscript and powershell command that can do it. But I need an LDAP query that can do it. Or anything that can be called from Java in a cross-platform way.

Here is the vbscript that can convert `northeast\nickd` into `CN=nickd,CN=Users,DC=northeast,DC=domain,DC=com`:

```
' Constants for the NameTranslate object.
Const ADS_NAME_INITTYPE_GC = 3
Const ADS_NAME_TYPE_NT4 = 3
Const ADS_NAME_TYPE_1779 = 1

' Specify the NetBIOS name of the domain.
strNetBIOSDomain = "northeast"

' Specify the NT name of the user.
strNTName = "nickd"

' Use the NameTranslate object to convert the NT user name to the
' Distinguished Name required for the LDAP provider.
Set objTrans = CreateObject("NameTranslate")
' Initialize NameTranslate by locating the Global Catalog.
objTrans.Init ADS_NAME_INITTYPE_GC, ""
' Use the Set method to specify the NT format of the object name.
objTrans.Set ADS_NAME_TYPE_NT4, strNetBIOSDomain & "\" & strNTName
' Use the Get method to retrieve the RFC 1779 Distinguished Name.
strUserDN = objTrans.Get(ADS_NAME_TYPE_1779)

' Escape any "/" characters with backslash escape character.
' All other characters that need to be escaped will be escaped.
strUserDN = Replace(strUserDN, "/", "\/")

Wscript.Echo strUserDN
```

And powershell:

```
$Name = "northeast"
$Domain = "nickd"

# Use the NameTranslate object.
$objTrans = New-Object -comObject "NameTranslate"
$objNT = $objTrans.GetType()

# Initialize NameTranslate by locating the Global Catalog.
$objNT.InvokeMember("Init", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $objTrans, (3, $Null))
# Specify NT name of the object.
# Trap error if object does not exist.
Try
{
    $objNT.InvokeMember("Set", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $objTrans, (3, "$Domain\$Name"))
    # Retrieve Distinguished Name of the object.
    $DN = $objNT.InvokeMember("Get", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $objTrans, 1)

    $DN
}
Catch
{
    "Bad name: $Domain\$Name"
}
```

related: https://serverfault.com/questions/234041/can-an-ldap-query-on-ad-provide-the-netbios-domain-name-for-a-single-account-whe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have figured it out. But I'm checking around to make sure.

I learned from internet searches that there is a special place in AD that stores the domains and their attributes `CN=Partitions,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=com`.

I was making the query to `CN=SOUTHEAST,CN=Partitions,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=com` but it was always missing the ldap object attributes that I needed, namely `ncname` which is the `DN` of the domain.

If you see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10886353/1174024) it states that the reason for my issue was that I was querying the global catalog! When you query the global catalog, you will be missing certain attributes.

So when doing multi-domain LDAP searches for users and groups, you do need to use the global catalog (port 3268 by default) or you won't get users/groups from sub-domains. But when doing an LDAP query to get the `DN` for a netbios domain, make sure to connect to the parent LDAP server and use the local ldap port (port 389 by default).

The query against `ldap://parent-ldap-host:389` becomes:

- Base DN: `CN=SOUTHEAST,CN=Partitions,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=com`
- Search filter: `(objectClass=*)`
- Search scope: `wholeSubtree`
- Attributes: `ncname`

This seems to work. Anything I am missing please comment below or add your own better answer. thanks.